# Adding posts to custom menu

Tags: customization, menus

I can’t see a “posts” box to check under the screen option of my custom menu. Help please. I’m lost.

Answer (score 0):

By default you can add posts to menus, so you should be able to see it.

There are two reasons, why you don't see it:

1. Some plugin/theme modified the built-in post type so it can't be added to menus (I don't believe anyone would try it).
2. You disabled posts in screen options. Go to Appearance -> Menus, click on "Screen options" tab in the top right corner and check if posts are checked in there: [image]